# Overriding Xcode setting

Tags: xcode, dynamic-linking

I have my project that contains a binary executable and a couple of dylibs.

In Xcode there is an option called `Dynamic Library Install Name` and `Dynamic Library Install Name Base`.

Right now they point to `/usr/local/lib` and `/usr/local/lib/mylibname.dylib`.

I thought I overrode it in the Post-Build script with the `install_name_tool -id` and `install_name_tool -change`. However, trying to execute the Bundle, I see an error that my dylib is still referenced from `/usr/local/lib`.

Is there a proper way to override `/usr/local/lib`?

Or can I simply set those 2 options to point to the Bundle Frameworks folder? But if I do that, how will it work? If I do clean and then build that folder will not exist yet.